# Martingales with power-law tails and CLT

Tags: martingale

I'm writing a course paper on stable distributions and I couldn't find any source discussing limits of Martingales with power-law tails. Suppose we have a Martingale that produces IID observations at constant intervals out of a distribution with finite variance, let's say once every moment t. If we collect observations of the Martingale on long enough intervals, eg. every 30t, following the Martingale CLT (and Classical CLT), our observations have the limit of Brownian motion.

What happens if the sampling distribution has power-law tails?
Do we get fractional Brownian motion as the limit?

I know Mandelbrot refers often to fractional Brownian motion and uses it to model stock returns which he assumes come from a distribution with power-law tails. However, I couldn't find any source where he gives any reasons other than visual for doing so.